# Add border to images

Tags: javascript, image, bookmarklet

I'm totally new to JS. I'm trying to make me a bookmarklet that finds all images on a web page and adds a colorful border to them. Then, by clicking on an image I'd like to attach the image path.
This is what I've got so far:

```
javascript:
for (var i= document.links.length; i-->0;) {
    if (document.links[i].getElementsByTagName('img').length!=0) {
        document.links[i].onclick= function() {
           window.open("http://www.example.com/whatever?imgsrc=" + this.src + "");
        };
    }
}
```

How can I add a border to the images?

Thanks,
Bob

Comment: your English isn't bad. You've only made one big mistake (than instead of then). I've seen worse. By the way, all images of a website or a web page? Those are two different things.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
javascript:for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName('img').length;i++){var imgTag=document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i];imgTag.style.border='2px solid #E8272C';imgTag.onclick=function(){return !window.open(this.src)};}void(0)
```

Friendly formatted view:

```
javascript:
for(i=0;i<document.getElementsByTagName('img').length;i++){
    var imgTag=document.getElementsByTagName('img')[i];
    imgTag.style.border='2px solid #E8272C';
    imgTag.onclick=function(){
        return !window.open(this.src);
    }
}void(0)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. There is just one thing I'ld like to know: Why does this code dosen't opening an external site? `imgTag.onclick=function(){return !window.open("http://www.myurl.com/#i/"+imgTag.src);}}void(0)`  I tried to replace the part in your example. Thanks

Comment: Just tried on current page, it works fine for image source from external URL(the icon above your comment.)

Comment: It's not opening the image I click on. I tried on several sites like http://ffffound.com. I just copy pasted your code. What do I wrong?

Comment: Thank you! So I tried to add a mouse over effect to it. Why is this not working?  `imgTag.onMouseOver=function(){imgTag.style.border='20px solid #ff0000';}` That's the last mystery to solve.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to call getElementsByTagName

```
javascript:(function(){for(var i=0;i<document.images.length;i++){var image=document.images[i];image.style.border='medium solid blue';image.onclick=function(){location.href=this.src;return false;};}})()
```